# ERROR:Xst:1534 - Sequential logic for node <rx_data> appears to be controlled by multiple clocks

Tags: vhdl, spi

I am new to VHDL and writing program for receiving the serial data, which is dependent on 2 clocks and one RESET signal.
One is FPGA's main source clock and another one is the external SPI master clock.

The written is like below:

```
    process(reset, main_clk, ext_clk)               
    begin
        if(reset = '0') then
        rx_data <= x"0000";
            elsif(chip_sel = '0') then
                if(ext_clk'event and ext_clk = '1') then    
--              rx_data <= rx_data;
                    if(main_clk'event and main_clk = '1') then
                    --- receiving data serially
```

But Xilinx tool is giving error:

> ERROR:Xst:1534 - Sequential logic for node <rx_data> appears to be controlled by multiple clocks.

How to overcome this error?

Comment: See [ask]. You've abstracted your problem to the extent what you're trying to do is unclear. There are no complete VHDL  statements nor declarations in your question. It appears you're trying to describe a serial shift register whose output is parallel loading into a register on a separate clock, yet the error message is saying you've named the parallel bus between them the same as the output register (rx_data). In general two different clocks shouldn't be evaluated in the same if or conditional signal assignment statement.  Draw it out, is it something like a 74HC595?

Comment: this code is for (Slave FPGA) receiving the 16-bit serial data from external SPI master (USB-SPI : MCP2210). Here I pasted the lines of initial receiving. So SPI master 's Serial clock and Slave FPGA's main clock are to be in sync right ?

Comment: It comes down to : learn digital hardware design as a separate topic from the language itself. Then you can use the language as a means of expressing that design. And a good basic rule is: use one clock for the entire design where you possibly can (as well as enable signals where you want to select some but not all clock edges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you use `'event` on `ext_clk` and `main_clk` which the tools use to infer clocks. Your design should only be sensitive to `main_clk` and `reset`. De